# Nested lists multiple levels get elements by name

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a nested lists with multiple levels and I want to extract elements by name.

I have a datasets with many metrics. The head looks like:

| Metric | Url |
| --- | --- |
| Domestic | https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossdomesticproductgdp/timeseries/njiq/ukea/data |
| International | https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossvalueaddedgva/timeseries/abml/pn2/data |

I retrieve JSON for all Url:

```
metrics <- lapply(dataset$Url, function(i) fromJSON(content(GET(i), as = 'text')))
```

I get from the JSON the sublists with years

```
metrics_years <- lapply(metrics, function (i) i$years)
```

Now I have a nested list with three levels. I get what I want for one metric if I do:

```
sapply(metrics_years[["Domestic"]], '[[', 'year')
```

But I cannot type for all of them. How can I obtain the same for all metrics without typing them one by one:

```
sapply(metrics_years[["Domestic"]], '[[', 'year')
sapply(metrics_years[["International"]], '[[', 'year')
...
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could be more specific, but based on your current description you could loop over names(nested_list), recursive functions, jsonlite::fromJSON(nested_list, flatten= TRUE) etc.

Comment: From what you gave your list only has a depth of 1 and the rest are dataframes. There is no level `domestic/international`. metric_years is a list of dataframes. Check your code again

Comment: thanks, since it is a list of dataframes, how could I get the year from each dataframe and for all metrics? You can see the structure of the JSON at https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossdomesticproductgdp/timeseries/njiq/ukea/data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't very much data in these files. I'm not sure what you're expecting. There are data frames called `years` and `quarters` in both lists. They both contain dates and values. Most of the content is NA.  Each is a time-series data set starting in 1962.  You don't need `httr`, either. `fromJSON` accepts a URL as a source without `content` or `GET`. `m <- map(1:2, ~fromJSON(d[.x], flatten = T)` where `d` is a vector with the two URLs. I think that's what @John Nielsen was stating. I used `map`, but `lapply` works fine, too.

You're using brackets, but you don't have to.

```
library(tidyverse) # for map and ggplot
library(jsonlite)

# get the JSON data and flatten it
mm <- map(1:2, ~fromJSON(d[.x], flatten = T))

# name each list, based on the URL
names(mm) <- c("Domestic", "International") 
attributes(mm) # validate change
```

You can access the content with the environment pane, to get an idea of what you have.

You can use `$` to access the content or `[[]]`. You can use numbers or names with `[[]]`.

```
all.equal(mm[[1]][[1]], mm$Domestic$years)
# [1] TRUE 

all.equal(mm[["Domestic"]][["years"]], mm$Domestic$years)
# [1] TRUE
```

To extract the data or to make a data frame-only object, you just need to assign it to an object name.

```
newDF <- mm$Domestic$years
```

You don't have to create a new object, though. If you wanted to plot the `Domestic years` data frame, you can use it as it is.

```
mm$Domestic$years %>% 
  mutate(year = as.integer(year), 
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value)) + geom_path() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

The `Domestic quarters` data

```
mm$Domestic$quarters %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(seq_along(value), value)) + geom_path() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = mm$Domestic$quarters[seq(1, 220, 50), ]$date,
                     breaks = seq(1, 220, 50)) +
  xlab("") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can do the same thing with the `International` data.

```
mm$International$years %>% 
  mutate(year = as.integer(year),
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value)) + geom_path() + theme_bw()
```